# Apache is not working after SSlcert configuration on alternate port

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, https, localhost

My Working url is given below which was working fine before ssl configuration. but after ssl cert configuration it is not working  it is returnnig me the error
which is given below.

```
Url :
   http://my-test-dev02.org.net:81

Error :

   This page isn’t working my-test-dev02.org.net redirected you too many times.
   Try clearing your cookies.
   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Apache configuration which i have is given below :

In 000-default.conf  File :

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
      
        Redirect permanent / https://my-test-dev02.org.net:81
        WSGIDaemonProcess skg-sa-ver12.org.net python-path=/volume/python3.8/site-packages
        WSGIScriptAlias / /c/my_dashboard/my_dashboard/wsgi.py
        <Directory "/c/my_dashboard/my_dashboard">

                Require all granted

        </Directory>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /c/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf File

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        #<VirtualHost *:443>

                WSGIScriptAlias / /c/my_dashboard/my_dashboard/wsgi.py
                ServerAdmin nehak@org.net
                
                <Directory "/c/my_dashboard/my_dashboard">
                  Require all granted
                </Directory>
                Alias /media/ /c/my_dashboard/my_dashboard/media/
                <Directory /c/my_dashboard/my_dashboard/media>
                    Require all granted
                </Directory>
                DocumentRoot /c/
  
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/certs/my-test-dev02_org_net/my-test-dev02_org_net.cer
                SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/certs/my-test-dev02_org_net.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In ports.conf file configuration i have :

```
Listen 81

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443 
</IfModule>
```

above is my configuration for ssl cert and apache. I don't know why i am  getting the error but without ssl cert i was able to access it. but after i am getting the error can anyone help me related this? what i am missing here and why this url is not securely redirecting ?

Comment: *"<VirtualHost *:81> ...  Redirect permanent / https://my-test-dev02.org.net:81"* - this makes no sense for me. You are redirecting from plain HTTP port 81 to HTTPS on same port. You probably want to redirect to HTTPS on the standard port (443).

Comment: Yes @SteffenUllrich I want to redirect to HTTPS. as much as I have debugged I found that issue is coming when I am uncommenting the permanent redirect.can you please suggest some ideas ??

Comment: Too much unknown about your exact setup, but you likely want to redirect to `https://my-test-dev02.org.net` not `https://my-test-dev02.org.net:81`, i.e. without the port 81 at the end.

Comment: I want to redirect on the https ://my-test-dev02.org.net:81 . wanted to execute on this.

Comment: This is not possible. You have plain HTTP on this port, not HTTPS.

Comment: Then how can I redirect to HTTPS with any other port? can you please guide me? I just wanted to use SSL Cert.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248011/discussion-between-neha-negi-and-steffen-ullrich).

Comment: I already said this: you have configured HTTPS on port 443, hence you likely want to redirect to this, not to a (non-existing) HTTPS on port 81. Therefore, use `https://my-test-dev02.org.net` (which uses the default port 443) not `https://my-test-dev02.org.net:81`